# Separating digits for large numbers in C# code

Tags: c#

In C++ you can separate the digits for readability in your code with apostrophes:

```
int num = 1'000'000;
```

In Ruby, you can use underscores:

```
num = 1_000_000
```

Is there a similar syntax for C#? I tried a few different searches but only came up with results for outputting or reading numbers in a particular format.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the underscore concept was considered / partially implemented in C#6, but didn't make it to release.

Comment: I know it's ugly but `int num = 1000000; // 1,000,000` could do the trick or even `int num = 1000000; // one million` for your exact example.

Comment: I'm not a C# guy but have a general distaste for non-trivial numeric literals in code, how about `const int ONE_MILLION = 1000000;` (or however you say that in C#) at the top of the file?

Comment: @Tunaki I don't disagree, but the issue I have here is using a *numeric literal* instead of a named constant. Worse sin, IMHO.

Comment: I usually break the number into factors, if I can, which sometimes makes it more readable. `int num = 1000 * 1000;`. If you're dealing with numbers of bytes in kB or MB it can be even better than the digit seperators: `int numBytes = 2 * 1024 * 1024;  // 2 MB`

Comment: @ZacCrites You could/should post that as an answer. If the one using a _less readable_ and culture-unsafe conversion from a string can get 6 upvotes, then surely you can't lose!* (*not legally binding)

Comment: A lot of these are good alternatives, since there isn't yet a standardized implementation as mentioned in the answer I selected. The example I used of one million might be too simple, but say there is some arbitrary limit or a static list of records that isn't a number that's easy to parse visually, like 325400058 or something. I think setting the constant is a good point to make it clear throughout the program what that number means. But having a standard separator will make it easier to prevent a mistake in that one location.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As of the time this answer is written, that feature does not exist in C#. However, there is a [feature request](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/216) for it, and it looks like it will be part of C# 7, which is the upcoming version.

The feature request is listed on their [C# 7 list of features](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/2136), but you probably shouldn't assume 100% it will make it in. Things are subject to change.

Comment: It looks like this has been implemented in C# 7 for Visual Studio 2017. You can do `int million = 1_000_000;`

Answer (score 1):

Small but handy little feature introduced in C# 7.0 is the digit separator character, which takes the form of a single underscore (_). This separator can be used within any numeric literal that means of improving legibility. Digit separator in a numeric literal does not change the value in anyway. Any given number is always the same to the common language run time, regardless of whether it uses separators or not.

```
// These two are equivalent.
var bigNumber      = 123456789012345678;
var bigNumberWithSplit = 123_456_789_012_345_678;
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't help with int, but with decimal you can use:

```
decimal num1 = 1E06M; // 1000000
decimal num2 = 1.23e06m; // 1230000
```

Answer (score -2):

In the meantime, you can still do this:

```
int num = Int32.Parse("1,000,000", NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
```

Comment: That means a very different thing than the C++ and Ruby versions. Why not just use a comment at that point? `int num = 1000000 //1,000,000`

Comment: @AssortedTrailmix Then the comment and the code can't fall out of sync.

Comment: Then somebody someday changes the current culture and the parsed numbers in the program are not all the same any more! If you really want to parse the number this way, you should add `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as a third parameter, because if you forget it even once, it's going to burn you!

Comment: ...do you think this _increases_ readability? and it would only get worse if made culture-safe, as noted above. avoid, avoid, avoid.